# Update Query with a few JOINs between tables and where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I have the following relations in MSSQL DB:
[image]

I want to make an UPDATE Query, where i can filter the first table values.
The example is as follows:

I want to get all Products from Inv_Transaction_Lines_Table, where Document_No from the first table(Gen_Documents_Table_1) is equal to '3250824' and State is 'Released'

The SELECT query is very simple:

```
SELECT        dbo.Inv_Transaction_Lines_Table.*, dbo.Inv_Transaction_Lines_Table.Product_Id AS Expr1, dbo.Gen_Documents_Table.Document_No, dbo.Inv_Transaction_Lines_Table.Quantity_Base AS Expr2
FROM            dbo.Gen_Documents_Table AS Gen_Documents_Table_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Inv_Transactions_Table RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Inv_Transaction_Lines_Table ON dbo.Inv_Transactions_Table.Transaction_Id = dbo.Inv_Transaction_Lines_Table.Transaction_Id ON 
                         Gen_Documents_Table_1.Id = dbo.Inv_Transactions_Table.Document_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Gen_Documents_Table ON Gen_Documents_Table_1.Master_Document_Id = dbo.Gen_Documents_Table.Id
WHERE        (Gen_Documents_Table_1.State = N'30') AND (dbo.Gen_Documents_Table.Document_No = N'3250824')
```

but I cannot manage with the UPDATE query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if your query for select is right ,you can use update on the same query for select .for example if you want update quantity_base :

```
update Inv_Transaction_Lines_Table set quantity_base = 'A'
FROM            dbo.Gen_Documents_Table AS Gen_Documents_Table_1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Inv_Transactions_Table RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Inv_Transaction_Lines_Table ON dbo.Inv_Transactions_Table.Transaction_Id = dbo.Inv_Transaction_Lines_Table.Transaction_Id ON 
                         Gen_Documents_Table_1.Id = dbo.Inv_Transactions_Table.Document_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Gen_Documents_Table ON Gen_Documents_Table_1.Master_Document_Id = dbo.Gen_Documents_Table.Id
WHERE        (Gen_Documents_Table_1.State = N'30') AND (dbo.Gen_Documents_Table.Document_No = N'3250824')
```